# How to calculate the result size of a select table query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

I wan to calculate result size from select table using query.
Like, **select * from product_table**

[products:    qty
Apple      3
Orange     4
pencil     2
pen        2
banana     3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uyeF.png)

From the query, i get 5 rows result.
How to calculate size from the result of the query (which is 5 rows) in megabyte (mb) or gigabyte (gb)